# wordpress site loads backlinks/spam links above header or below footer

Tags: wordpress

My website http://spigroup.ae loads the empty space below the footer or above the header.
I've tried to scan with multiple anti virus plugins but no luck.

When i do the inspect elements on the page i can see the line which is loading ""(empty space) and some text with hyper links to http://forbrukslånportalen.net.

When i go through the my wordpress core files i can not see the same text or hyper links, some maleware script running on my site loading this hyper links dynamically.

Please let me know if any one of u can help me out in this regards.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress offers this advice in their FAQ:

http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

But basically, the hacked code could be in one of three places:

1. The WordPress core files - to check, download the core files from wordpress.org and copy them over the top of your current installation. This won't affect your theme or plugins or any uploaded content.
2. Your current theme - to check, try activating another theme and see if the spam code / links remain. (It may also be in a plugin, so try deactivating them all as well).
3. The database - to check, open phpMyAdmin, navigate to your database, then click "Search". Choose all the tables in the database, and search for part of the pattern, surrounding your search term with percent signs. For example:

   %portalen%

Remember to back up your website before you do anything!

Comment: I've tried the options 1 & 2 but no luck. The option 3 is not useful because external content which is loading on my web page is not my wordpress files or on data base, it seems the content loading dynamically using a script.</br> The only suspectable string(display:none). This i could find on database but in many places, It is hard to traceout.